# How to give the target bucket log-delivery group WRITE and READ_ACP permissions?

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-cloudfront, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to setup a cloudfront dist and s3 bucket with terraform. When I run `terraform apply` it is returning the following error:

> - aws_s3_bucket.app: Error putting S3 logging: InvalidTargetBucketForLogging: You must give the log-delivery group WRITE and READ_ACP permissions to the target bucket

my S3.tf file:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3_policy" {
  policy_id = "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent"

  statement {
    sid       = "1"
    actions   = ["s3:GetObject"]
    resources = ["arn:aws:s3:::${local.name_env}/*"]

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["${aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.origin_access_identity.iam_arn}"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "app" {
  bucket = "${local.name_env}"
  policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.s3_policy.json}"

  logging {
    target_bucket = "${local.logs_bucket}"
    target_prefix = "app-${var.environment}"
  }

  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }

  tags = "${local.tags}"
}
```

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=21227

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/enable-logging-programming.html#grant-log-delivery-permissions-general

Comment: @BMW Thanks for the response. I came across those two resources also. 
In the first link, I'm unsure which "property field" the final answer is referring to, and in the second link is talking about managing it with java sdk or .net so I wasn't sure how that applied to my current terraform/cloudformation

Comment: realised, this feature doesn't ready in terraform, the PR is not merged:  https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/3757

Comment: Here is the discussion about this feature: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/989

Comment: @BMW Hmm, strange. It has definitely worked on other builds. Is there maybe a way I could disable logs all together to get past this error?

Comment: You could remove the logging config block from your S3 bucket if you want to disable logging. But if you want to enable it you just need to add the necessary permissions to allow logging.

Comment: Yeah, my question @ydaetskcoR is how exactly do I add the necessary permissions to allow logging.

Comment: Are you logging to a different bucket or the same one?

Answer (score 17):

You need to add an `acl` attribute to your aws_s3_bucket with a value of "log-delivery-write".

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "app" {
  bucket = "${local.name_env}"
  acl = "log-delivery-write"
  ...
}
```

Comment: You might want to tighten this up. OP shows a logging target of `local.logs_bucket` without defining that resource. Adding the acl to the app bucket will not solve OPs problem.

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE: terraform now supports custom bucket acls natively. What follows is a workaround for older versions where the predefined acls would not suffice.

Here's how to achieve this via terraform using a null resource and the AWS CLI.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "files_bucket" {
  # ...

  logging {
    target_bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.logs_bucket.bucket}"
  }

  depends_on = [
    "null_resource.logs_bucket_acl_workaround"
  ]
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket" "logs_bucket" {
  # ...
  acl    = "private"
}


locals {
  put_bucket_acl_cmd = "s3api put-bucket-acl --bucket ${aws_s3_bucket.logs_bucket.bucket} --grant-write 'uri=\"http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/s3/LogDelivery\"' --grant-read-acp 'uri=\"http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/s3/LogDelivery\"'"
}

resource "null_resource" "logs_bucket_acl_workaround" {
  # cannot set bucket ACLs via terraform yet
  # https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/989
  depends_on = [
    "aws_s3_bucket.logs_bucket",
  ]

  triggers = {
    bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.logs_bucket.bucket}"
    command = "${local.put_bucket_acl_cmd}"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws ${local.put_bucket_acl_cmd}"
  }
}
```

Note that ACLs in this way are only added but never removed.

Comment: AWS has predefined grants that can be used with in the `aws_s3_bucket` resource. Here's the [Terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/s3_bucket.html#enable-logging) showing it used in action and here's the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl) explaining the predefined grants

Comment: Sometimes the predefined grants are not enough. For example if you have log delivered from S3 and cloudfront. Anyhow that should be supported in latest terraform without the workaround